# python how to get today, variable with quote

Tags: python, string, variables

What I need is how to get today's date with quote sign, "2022-08-14".

The date can be changed on daily basis, and the quote sign, ", stayed at the begining and the end.

having to do with the sign, &, or not.  I cant figured it out.  Thanks in advance

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
n=0
today = date.today() - timedelta(days = n)
print(today)
print("today")
print("", today , "")
```

This is what I got from above print

2022-08-14

today

2022-08-14

Comment: What is wrong with the current output? I don't think you need the quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the quotes in the string, e.g.

```
print('"', today, '"')
```

You could also use triple quotes:

```
print(""""""", today, """"""")
```

but that looks harder to read to me.

Your code is incorrect because you've got *empty* strings either side of `today`.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to use f-string `f'"{today}"'`?

Answer (score 0):

In python, to print the double quote `"` as a string not a symbol, you can use `\"` inside the quotes like `print("\"")`

Or you can just use single quotes wrapping a double quote (`print('"')`)

In your case, I think the simplest solution is to use f-string where variable inside `{}` will be printed like string

```
print(f'"{today}"')
```

This is most basic grammar and I recommend you do some web search before asking here

Comment: Thanks for your answer and nicely explained.

(I did the web search before ask for help. )